# Javascript loop not setting PHP value via sqlite_fetch_array() when adding series in Highcharts

Tags: php, javascript, sqlite, highcharts, linechart

I have a SQLite database and am trying to graph data on a linechart using Highcharts, PHP, and Javascript. I am graphing one series per user (a user being a text value per tuple), but am running into trouble with retrieving a subsequent user via a PHP loop.

```
$dbhandle = sqlite_open('db/test.db', 0666, $error);

if (!$dbhandle) die ($error);
$query5 = "SELECT DISTINCT User FROM Events";

$ok0 = sqlite_query($dbhandle, $query5, $error_msg);

if (!$ok0) 
{
    die("dead" . $error_msg);
}
$rows = sqlite_num_rows($ok0);

echo 
"for(var i=2; i<$rows; i++) // start of JS loop. 
                           //$rows is 4; I am graphing 2 series here
{";

  $array = sqlite_fetch_array($ok0, SQLITE_ASSOC); // $ok0 is the unique list
// of users. After graphing one series, I want to grab the next user to graph


        echo "chart.addSeries({
                name: '{$array["User"]}',
                data: [";
          for($i=0; $i<$diff+1; $i++)
          {
            $target = date("D, j M", (strtotime($_GET["start"]) + $i * 24 * 3600));
            $query6 = "SELECT * FROM Events WHERE User = '{$array["User"]}' AND Start LIKE '%{$target}%'";
            $result6 = sqlite_query($dbhandle, $query6);
            if (!$result6) die("Cannot execute query.");
            $num = sqlite_num_rows($result6);            
            if($i==($diff))
            {
              echo $num;
            }              
            else
              echo $num . ", ";
          }?>],

                pointStart: 


                 <?php
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('D M d Y', urldecode($_GET["start"])); 
echo $date->getTimestamp()*1000;?>,
            pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000 // one day

              });
      <?php echo "}";?> // end of JS loop
```

The result does graph two additional series, but they are both the same data from the same user. It doesn't look like the loop with sqlite_fetch_array() correctly returns the next user. Can anyone see the problem here? Maybe something with the way I'm integrating Javascript with PHP?

Comment: If you take a look your code you'll see that you have many sintax erros, other problem is that you're building javascript thrue php.
How about separate them ?

Comment: I'm not sure that there are syntax errors, since there is a resulting graph with two series graphed by this snippet. It is messy with combining PHP with echoing Javascript snippets though. I'm wondering if someone can see the problem though?

Comment: maybe I'm just unfamiliar with sqlite functions, but I don't see anything that would increment $array - your query seems to be using the same $array["User"] every time. Correct me if I'm wrong? Maybe you need to wrap the whole thing in a while() loop?

Comment: The function sqlite_fetch_array() fetches the next row from a result set as an array. I'm not sure why it wouldn't in this case; I'm echoing the Javascript for loop from PHP, and I assume sqlite_fetch_array() would continually grab the next user for each loop. Hence $array["User"] should return the next user for each iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out. I believe that due to PHP being executed server-side, the block of code within the echoed Javascript loop results in the same values when the browser executes the Javascript. The server simply echoes the string that represents the js loop, and will run the code block after. When everything is sent to the browser, the Javascript will loop normally and simply output the results of the code block twice. I've just forgone the JS loop via PHP and replaced it with a PHP loop.

Answer (score 0):

This line of code always does the same thing every time you call it:

```
$query6 = "SELECT * FROM Events WHERE User = '{$array["User"]}' AND Start LIKE '%{$target}%'";
```

`$array` supposedly has a list of distinct users, but you don't show the query for `$ok0`. You're doing the user lookup inside this loop `for($i=0; $i<$diff+1; $i++)`, but you use none of those variables in determining which user to fetch.

I'd like to post the correct way to look up the next user from `$array`, but I have no idea what the structure is. If you can't figure out how to make your `$query6` unique to each user, you'll have to post more information, like a `var_dump` of `$array` or the query text of `$ok0`.

Maybe you just need to move this line `$array = sqlite_fetch_array($ok0, SQLITE_ASSOC);` inside your `for` loop, but then you run the risk of `$i` and `$diff+1` disagreeing with the number of rows available from your result.

Comment: Thanks, I've added the snippet. For a given iteration, $query6 is intended to grab the current user and date. The nested loop for($i=0; $i<$diff+1; $i++) grabs the data for a date range for a given user. I have it so that when we get to that nested loop, we've grabbed the next user from $array via $array = sqlite_fetch_array($ok0, SQLITE_ASSOC). I'm trying to have sqlite_fetch_array() fetch the next user for every iteration of the parent Javascript loop for(var i=2; i<$rows; i++).